# Django app performing slowly (even when cached)

Tags: django

Launching my second-ever Django site.

I've had problems in the past with Django's ORM (basically, the SQL it was generating just wasn't what I wanted and even using things like `select_related()` I couldn't wrangle it into what it should've been) -- I ended up just writing all my DB queries by hand in my views and using this function, taken from the Django docs, to turn the `cursor`'s responses into usable dictionaries:

```
def dictfetchall(cursor, returnMultiDictAnyway=False):
    "Returns all rows from a cursor as a dict"
    desc = cursor.description
    rows = [
        dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]

    if len(rows) == 1 and not returnMultiDictAnyway:
        return rows[0]
    return rows
```

I'm almost ready to launch my site but I'm finding pretty huge performance problems on the two different webservers I've tried hosting the app with.

Locally, it doesn't run blazingly fast, but I generally put this down to my machine in general being a little slow. I don't have the numbers to hand (will add later on) but the SQL times aren't crazily high and I've made the effort to optimise MySQL (adding missing indexes etc).

Here's the app, running on two different webhosts (using bit.ly to avoid Google spidering these URLs, sorry!):

- http://bit.ly/10iEWYt (hosted on Dreamhost, using Passenger WSGI)
- http://bit.ly/UZ9adS (hosted on WebFaction, also using WSGI)

At the moment I have `Debug=False` on both of those hosts (so there shouldn't be a loading penalty) and a file-based cache of 15 minutes for each one. On the Dreamhost one I have an experimental cronjob hitting the homepage every 15 minutes in an effort to see if this keeps the Python server alive -- this doesn't seem to have done much.

If you try those links you should see how long it takes for the server to respond as you click around, even including the cache (try going from the homepage to another page then back home).

I've tried [this profiling middleware](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/605/) but not really sure how to interpret results (can add them to this post later on when I'm home) -- in any case, the functions/lines it pointed to were all inside Django's own code so I struggled to relate that to my own views etc.

Is it likely that the `dictfetchall()` method above could be an issue here? I use that to work with the results of every DB query on the site (~5-10 per page, most on the homepage). I do have a few included templates but nothing too crazy. I have a context processor for common things like showing album reviews, which I use all over the place. I'm stumped about what else could be causing this slowness.

Thanks, hope this is enough info to be helpful.

EDIT: okay, here's a profiling trace of the site homepage: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=c7kHNXAZ -- struggling to interpret it, to be honest.

Also, I looked at the Debug Toolbar stats: 8 SQL queries in 246ms (looking currently at further optimising these), but total time for render of 3235ms (locally). This is what's confusing me.